# Is put() on an access-ordered LinkedHashMap a structural modification even if an item with the specified key already exists?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

Title say it all:

There is a slight ambiguity in the documentation as I understand it.
First the documentation speaks about insertion-ordered LinkedHashMap's and notes that the iteration order is not affected upon inserting an item already mapped.

Then, it introduces access-ordered LinkedHashMap's and insists on the fact that "merely a get is a structural modification", i.e. it affects iteration order.

But, it is not clear whether the ''put()'' of an existing item is a structural modification.

I expect the answer to be yes.

Comment: Your best option is to just try it out. It should be very simple to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple piece of code should answer your question:

```
final Map<String, String> x = new LinkedHashMap<>(10, 0.75f, true);
x.put("a", "a");
x.put("b", "b");
System.out.println(x);
x.put("a", "a");
System.out.println(x);
```

prints

```
{a=a, b=b}
{b=b, a=a}
```

Interpretation: `put` under an existing key, even with the same value, is a structural modification.

Comment: +1 the documentation says "access order" which implies reads and writes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The corner case is when nothing is necessarily written, but implicitly a read had to be made in order to conclude this.

Comment: HashMap is a little dumb when it comes to updating a key. It creates a new Entry first and then tires to find somewhere to put it (or replace the original)

Comment: @PeterLawrey While we're on the "dumb" page, I'm quite irritated by `HashSet` being just a thin layer over `HashMap`, instantiating a `Map.Entry` for each element.

Comment: Which is what `Collections.newSetForMap` does if you really want that.  In theory, the JVM can optimise that away but I suspect it doesn't. Trove4j implements the Map as an extension of the Set. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, actually the plain old `HashSet` is a wrapper over `HashMap`. It has virtually no functionality of its own. `add(x)` is implemented as `put(x, dummyObject)`.